# Port of CreateFile INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c#

So I'm porting this stuff from c++ to c#.  And part of it looks like this:

```
      m_hParstat = CreateFile( _T("\\\\.\\LPTSTAT1"), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );

  if( m_hParstat == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
     // do some stuff
  }
```

So in my c# code I've got

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
                     uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
                     uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

public const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x00000080;
public const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
public const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
public const UInt32 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = 0xffffffff;
```

And then

```
  m_hParstat = CreateFile("\\\\.\\LPTSTAT1", GENERIC_READ, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, IntPtr.Zero);
  if (m_hParstat.ToInt32() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {

  }
```

But VS is saying that the comparison is useless because the constant is outside the range of int.  How do I check my handle for a valid value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its most likely because your constant is not an Int32.  Change:

```
public const UInt32 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = 0xffffffff;
```

to

```
public const Int32 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;
```

Another option is to change the `CreateFile` definition to return a [`SafeFileHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.aspx) instead of an `IntPtr`.  Then you can use the [`IsInvalid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandlezeroorminusoneisinvalid.isinvalid.aspx) and [`IsClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.isclosed.aspx) properties.

Answer (score 3):

Converting an `IntPtr` to 32 bits when you're running on a 64-bit system is going to *lose information*. `m_hParstat.ToInt32()` will throw away the top 32 bits, meaning that you could potentially be saying that something is invalid when it isn't.

If you're not testing all the bits of the return value, then you have a potential bug in your program.

Your best bet would be to use [SafeFileHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have VS where I am now, but have you tried to compare it by calling ToInt64() instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UIntPtr` as return type and change `m_hParstat.ToInt32()` to `m_hParstat.ToUInt32()`.

Comment: I think this would work, but SwDevMan81 has an even simpler solution.